# Android: Passing object from Activity to Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I follow this link [Pass data from activity to service](http://android-coding.blogspot.it/2011/11/pass-data-from-activity-to-service-via.html) for understanding the passage of data from Activity to Service Android. The problem is that I need to pass a complex object to Service. How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 8):

You can make your complex object implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and then you can pass it to Service using `putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` or `putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)`

[Here](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html) you can find a tutorial for implementing `Parcelable` and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaSerialization/article.html) `Serializable` one.

If you aren't familiar with an any of them I would suggest you to use `Serializable' since it's more simple and pretty straightforward

Comment: Ok. Can you suggest any tutorial for implementing Serializable or Parcelable?

Comment: Will this object that we send to the service persist in the service even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Passing in custom objects is a little more complicated. You could just mark the class as Serializable
and let Java take care of this. However, on the android, there is a serious performance hit that comes with using Serializable. The solution is to use Parcelable.

Refer the examples:

http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Comment: Thank you. But I don't care about performance, because my parameter passage is made just once. So I may use Serializable. Afeter I marked the class as Serializable how can I have to pass parameter?